# Create List of Distinct Rows Dynamically, and Pivot?

Tags: sql-server

Here is my DDL and DML:

```
CREATE TABLE EAVTable
(
        RecordID INT NOT NULL,
    Element CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Value SQL_VARIANT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (RecordID, Element)
)
GO

-- Insert some records
INSERT INTO EAVTable (RecordID, Element, Value) VALUES
(1, 'FirstName', 'Klaus'),
(1, 'LastName', 'Aschenbrenner'),
(1, 'City', 'Vienna'),
(1, 'Country', 'Austria'),
(2, 'FirstName', 'Bill'),
(2, 'LastName', 'Gates'),
(2, 'City', 'Seattle'),
(2, 'Country', 'USA')
GO


Select *
From EAVTable
```

Result:

[image]

I know how to pivot, by hard coding the field names.

```
Select *
From EAVTable
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(Element)
    FOR Value In ([Aschenbrenner],
            [Austria],
            [Bill],
            [Gates],
            [Klaus],
            [Seattle],
            [USA],
            [Vienna])
) PVT
```

[image]

Now, I am trying to figure out how to generate those filed names dynamically.  I just tested this script.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=
STUFF(
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + Value + ']'
    FROM EAVTable
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
,1,1,'');

DECLARE @SqlCmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
'SELECT p.*
 FROM
 (
    SELECT *
    FROM tempData
 ) AS tbl
 PIVOT
 (
    Max(Element) FOR Value IN(' +  @cols +')
 ) AS p';

 EXEC(@SqlCmd);
```

I got this result.

```
Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 65
The data types varchar and sql_variant are incompatible in the add operator.
```

I don't see an add operator, so I think the error message is a bit deceiving.  Also, how would one go about debugging this?  If I try to run:  `print(@SqlCmd)`

I get the same error message as described above.

I am using SQL Server 2017 Express Edition.

Comment: What do you think `',[' + Value + ']' ` is?

Comment: I changed the data type.  From: Value SQL_VARIANT
To: Value varchar(100)
Now it works!